# How can I reject numbers in a string using try except in python?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I need to reject any numerical values in the string using try except

```
try:
    name = str(input('please enter a name: '))
except ValueError:
    print('error')
```

Comment: *Any* input is a string. `str()` ain't gonna do nothing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
try:
    name = input('please enter a name: ')
    if any(i.isdigit() for i in name):
        raise ValueError('Name must not contain any digits')
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Of course, just `if any(..): print('Name must not ...')` would be a lot simpler than the superfluous `try..raise..except` construction.

Comment: Op asked for using try except?

Comment: Yeah, whatever they did that for… I'd have expected the difficult bit being the `any..isdigit` part; if you need to turn this into an exception conditionally because it makes sense in your code, fine. Just this tiny snippet here as is makes no sense…